# Как создать шорткоды для админки Джанго?

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть модель `City`. В ней есть поле `name`. Нужно каким-то образом в админке в текстовом поле подставлять эту переменную. Предположим, нужно написать фразу "Ваше местонахождения - `Париж`", но нужно, что название города подставилось само (так как городов много, а прописывать для каждого - не вариант совсем). То есть, должно быть что-то вроде "Ваше местонахождения - `{City.name}`" - то есть определённый город вытаскивается из бд и подставляется в эту строку. Писать заготовленную фразу в шаблонах - не вариант. Нужно делать это через админку. Я так, понимаю, нужно создать поле `shortcode_name` и как-то во вьюхе его обрабатывать?

Comment: [ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) или [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2).

Comment: Это Джанго 1.11. Селекты - не вариант.

Comment: django-select2 нормально работает с 1.11

Comment: Но использовать их не вариант. предположим, будет фраза в текстовом поле "Столица {country.name} - {City.name}. Как тогда быть? Я это к тому, что количество переменных, место их расположения и фраза - заранее неизвестны.

Comment: Тогда на бэкенде надо поднимать движок полнотекстового поиска, писать работающие с ним представления и отправлять запросы к нему из того же select2.

Comment: Вроде, как-то через `.format(City.name="")` можно или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь в методе `__init__` в форме админки указать `initial` для поля
Ниже пример, где `get_city_name()` - то, как вы хотите получать название города

```
# Форма
class ModelAModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city_name = models.CharFielf(max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city_name'].initial = get_city_name()

# Админка
class ModelAModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelAModelForm
```